# ImportError: No module named... & Unresolved reference in pycharm

Tags: django

Trying to run a management command with no success.
Was getting an error in terminal ImportError, and in my IDE it would not resolve the models.
I found the answer and the issue was that I was not running the management command via manage.py.

The error in terminal would come up when running

`../management/commands$ python import_puzzle.py`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling the management command directly from it's folder. You should run it from the src folder using manage.py:

```
`../src$ python manage.py import_puzzle`
```

The reason is that `import_puzzle` is actually a management command and must be called using the manage.py. I'm too much of a beginner to elaborate any further! :)